# Maximize rabbit pen size (no calc)

Tags: geometry, quadratics, rectangles

**Question:**

To make an enclosure for your pet rabbits, you want to fence a rectangular pen against your house. Only 3 sides will need to be fenced. You have 170 feet of fencing material, and want to maximize the pen area.

**a.** Write a quadratic function (in standard form) to represent the area of the rectangular enclosure, where x is the width.

**b.** What dimensions will maximize the area of the enclosure?

**c.** What is the maximum area of the enclosure?

I believe that this type of problem can be solved with calculus, but I am in an algebra class, so please avoid the use of calculus.

**My Attempt:**

I'm pretty lost, when it comes to this problem. My best guess is that the Area$=(170/3)^2=28900/9$, since a square has the largest area among quadrilaterals with equal perimeters. I really have no clue how to solve this, though.

Thanks in advance

Comment: hint: $2x+y=170$ so $A = xy = x(170-2x)$

Comment: Because you don't need fence along the house, the square shape isn't necessarily optimal. You might even start by just trying some different specific possibilities for the dimensions of the pen.

Comment: @paw88789 You are perfectly right. In fact the solution is a rectangle with length = $2  \ \times$  width.

Comment: In the identical question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2092692/305862), have a look at a remarkable answer using inequality Arithmetical Mean $\ge$ Geometrical Mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with putting the given information into equation form:

Total length of fence: L = 170.

Area enclosed: S = x*y,

where x is the length transverse to the house and y is the length parallel to the house.

In terms of the sides, the total length can be written as:

L = y + 2x = 170,

because there is one side parallel to the house and two sides transverse to the house.

We want to relate this to the area x*y so we can conveniently multiply everything in the equation for L by x to get:

$x y + 2 x^2 = 170 x$

$S + 2 x^2 = 170 x$

$S = 170 x - 2x^2 $

Put this into standard quadratic form by equating everything to zero

$-2 x^2 +170 x - S = 0$

This answers question (a).

Now back to the area formula we derived above:

$S = 170 x - 2x^2 $

If you [plot this equation for the area](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+s+%3D+170x+-+2x%5E2) you will see the maximum or peek value is between the two roots where the curve crosses the x axis, due the symmetry of the curve.

The quadratic formula for solving for the roots is:

$\frac{-B \pm \sqrt{B^2 - 4 A C}}{2 A}$

where A = -2, B = 170 and C = S (Area) from our standard form quadratic.

If we rewrite the quadratic equation as:

$\frac{-B}{2 A} \pm \frac{\sqrt{B^2 - 4 A C}}{2 A}$,

it is easy to see that the midpoint between the two roots is simply: $$\frac{-B}{2A}$$

This is the x value when the area is at a maximum. We can find the area by using this value of x in the $S = 170 x - 2x^2 $ equation we obtained earlier. This answers question (b).

The y value can found by substituting x into the $y + 2x = 170$ equation we found earlier. This answers question (c)

Comment: Please, see my comment above.

Answer (score 2):

Geometric solution:

Cutting the rectangle in half (splitting perpendicular to the open side), leaves two identical rectangles, both with a height of $y$ and a base of $x/2$ and the perimeter restriction is equivalent to the sum of the width and length of each piece being $85$. As you know, a square maximizes area when the sum of the width and length (half the perimeter) is fixed, so the best shape for them is $85/2$ by $85/2$, so the best shape is 85 by 42.5.